# Dynamic nginx domain root path based on hostname?

Tags: php, nginx, virtualhost

I am trying to setup my development nginx/PHP server with a basic master/catch-all vhost config so that I can [created unlimited `___.framework.loc` domains](https://gist.github.com/4262132) as needed.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        # Test 1
        server_name ~^(.+)\.frameworks\.loc$;
        set $file_path $1;
        root    /var/www/frameworks/$file_path/public;

        include /etc/nginx/php.conf;
}
```

However, nginx responds with a 404 error for this setup. I know nginx and PHP are working and have permission because the `localhost` config I'm using works fine.

```
server {
        listen 80 default;
        server_name localhost;
        root /var/www/localhost;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        include /etc/nginx/php.conf;
}
```

What should I be checking to find the problem? Here is a copy of that php.conf they are both loading.

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {

        try_files $uri =404;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        # Keep these parameters for compatibility with old PHP scripts using them.
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        # Some default config
        fastcgi_connect_timeout        20;
        fastcgi_send_timeout          180;
        fastcgi_read_timeout          180;
        fastcgi_buffer_size          128k;
        fastcgi_buffers            4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size    256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors    on;
        fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not just use:

```
server_name *.frameworks.loc;
root /var/www/frameworks/$http_host/public;
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 14):

Nginx config is not a program, it's a declaration.
When you are using config like this:

```
server {
        server_name ~^(.+)\.frameworks\.loc$;
        ...
        set $file_path $1;
        root    /var/www/frameworks/$file_path/public;
}
```

There's no way to ensure that your `set` directive will execute before `root`.

But there's a trick with `map` directive I like to use. It relies on fact that `map` is evaluated before `location`

```
http {
  map $http_host $rootpath {
    ~^(.?<mypath>+)\.frameworks\.loc$  $mypath;
    default                            /      ;
  }
  ....
  root /var/www/frameworks/$rootpath
}
```

Comment: This looks like fun, I plan on playing more with map now. I also was not aware that the configuration files were not processed in a linear fashion.

Comment: What's the point of `$mypath` here? It's not used anywhere.

Comment: @kodeart `$mypath` is the result group for regex `~^(.?<mypath>+)\.frameworks\.loc$` and `$rootpath` is the result for whole map trick.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to great [DukeLion's](https://serverfault.com/a/459572/309693) answer, I needed to change line

`~^(.?<mypath>+)\.frameworks\.loc$  $mypath;`

to

`~^(?P<mypath>.+)\.frameworks\.loc$  $mypath;`

in my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/a/482391).

Adding

`root /var/www/frameworks/$rootpath`

in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` worked fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can look into lighttpd also. It has build in support for exactly what you are asking here. It is call **mod_evhost**.

**Enable evhost**

Add following lines into your lighttpd.conf. If you are using Debian/Ubuntu base distribution, just soft link or copy from `/etc/lighttpd/conf-available/10-evhost.conf` to `/etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/`.

```
    # http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:ModEVhost
    server.modules += ( "mod_evhost" )
    evhost.path-pattern = "/home/www/%_"
```

The `%_` (wildcard) in evhost.path-patten means use the full domain name (eg. www.example.com). A request for www.example.com will automatically direct to document-root `/home/www/www.example.com/`.

Adding additional site is as easy as creating another directory under `/home/www` with full domain name. No change to Lighttpd config file.

There are other wildcards and can be used to build directory structure. They are as follow

```
    %% => % sign
    %0 => domain name + tld
    %1 => tld
    %2 => domain name without tld
    %3 => subdomain 1 name
    %4 => subdomain 2 name
    %_ => full domain name
```

Detail information is [here](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:ModEVhost).

**PS:** Enabling PHP is also easy if you are on debian/ubuntu platform. Just enable `10-fastcgi.conf` and `15-fastcgi-php.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

NGINX uses the PCRE regular expression library.
As of NGINX v0.8.25 [`server_name` directive allows **named captures**](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name).

> **Named captures** in regular expressions create variables (**0.8.25**) that can later be used in other directives
>   While using named parenthesis, NGINX automatically sets a variable for each named parenthesis, during server names evaluation (I guess).

I use the following snippet to "fence" developers environments. «user» refers to their username and «proj» the project they work on:

```
# ...
server_name ~^(?<user>[^.]+)\.(?<proj>[^.]+).dev.local-server.com;
root /home/$user/www/$proj;
# ...
```

Note that nginx configuration is declarative, and as such, static declarations might always be faster compared to run-time calculated values and variables. Regular expressions evaluation is relatively costly, I guess it has to be used with parsimony in heavy loaded (production) environments.