# Is there any soft / hard limit on the number of virtual hosts that Nginx can handle?

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

And what are performance implications? Is it practical to host tens of thousands of vhosts on one Nginx instance? How much would the increased latency be?

We plan to offer custom domains for users, and to assign different chroot per user and to serve static assets like js/css directly from nginx, we want to host as many users per nginx instance as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't require dynamic content, fastcgi daemons etcetera, unlimited vhosts can be as simple as this [SF answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/457196/dynamic-nginx-domain-root-path-based-on-hostname).

```
server_name *.dom.tld;
root /var/www/$http_host/public;
```

In that case, your first bottleneck will likely be the filesystem, not Nginx.

Also note that major reverse proxies such as Cloudflare use (a modified version of) Nginx, so it sounds plausible to do.

Comment: Thanks! Is "server_name *;" an acceptable value? When we use custom domains, not subdomains. Then it's a perfect solution!

Comment: Yes, see also: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html
So I wonder, How come this question is still relevant after almost 2 years? ;)

Comment: Took another route at the time - now I'm commenting out of pure interest. :)

Comment: @kenn which route did you ultimately take?