# nginx httpMapModule regex variables

Tags: nginx, regex, regular-expressions

The [HttpMapModule documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMapModule) states that:

> Since 1.0.4, case insensitive regular expressions can be used by prefixing the pattern with ~*.

And gives the example:

```
map $uri $myvalue {
    /aa                   /mapped_aa;
    ~^/aa/(?<suffix>.*)$  $suffix;
}
```

I updated to `nginx/1.2.7` to make use of this, and naive regexes work okay, but variables don't. When I try the above syntax I get the error:

```
nginx: [emerg] pcre_compile() failed: unrecognized character after (?< in "^/aa/(?<suffix>.*)$" at "suffix>.*)$"
```

I also tried the following syntaxes, but none of them worked:

```
~^(.*)$  $1;
~^(.*)$  \1;
```

but neither of them worked either.

Does anyone know how to get variables to work in regular expressions in HttpMapModule?

Comment: Your example works for me with nginx 1.1.19 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @mgorven that's odd. Could you confirm this is definitely true? Maybe it changed between 1.1.19 and 1.2.7. In which case I was wrong to update the documentation: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMapModule#map

Comment: Yup, I copy/pasted your example into my config.

Comment: Works for me in 2023 on Nginx 1.25

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`(?P<name>pattern)` is the standard PCRE syntax for named capture-groups - the documentation is missing a `P`.

The ["Named Subpatterns" section on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) states that `(?<name>...)` and `(?'name'...)` are valid for PCRE 7.0 onwards; presumably your version of nginx is linked against an earlier version of PCRE.

Comment: Wonderful. That is the answer. How did you know that? Where would I find PCRE documentation that explains `P` variables? (I did search for it)

Comment: I've updated the documentation: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMapModule