# Nginx root based on hostname without www

Tags: nginx, centos7

English is not my native language, please accept my apologies for any language issues.

I want a configuration with automatic root, regardless of domain, look like this (using nginx):

```
root /var/www/${http_host}/public
```

But I want the root domain and the "www" to point to the same directory, but without the "www":

### Example:

1. "**www.mysite.com**" and "**mysite.com**"

   *root /var/www/**mysite.com**/public*
2. But "**blog.mysite.com**"

   *root /var/www/**blog.mysite.com**/public*

---

That is, only the "www" should point to the directory that does not have "www" in the name.

Yes I saw that there are other similar questions ([like this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/457196/dynamic-nginx-domain-root-path-based-on-hostname)), but I had difficulty removing the "www". Excuse me!

I will not use such a generic **server_name**, but this should work even with:

```
server_name ~.+$;
```

But also so:

```
listen 443 ssl http2;

server_name ~ ^((www|blog|account|bbs)\.)?mysite.com$;

root /var/www/${http_host}/public

ssl_certificate /ssl/${http_host}/{http_host}.pem
ssl_certificate_key /ss/${http_host}/{http_host}.key
```

*NOTE: It should work with from the ssl certificate path.*

Comment: I wonder if you could assign the non-www part of the http_host variable to a new variable using a regular expression capture group. Regular expression might be something like "^([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(.*)?(#[\w\-]+)?$" (without speech marks), but I don't know off the top of my head how to assign this to a variable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `map` in the `http` block like this:

```
map $http_host $rootdir {
    ~^(?:www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$ $domain;
}
```

And then you use the following in your `server` block:

```
root /var/www/${rootdir}/public;
```

In the `map` directive, we convert `$http_host` variable containing the HTTP request `Host` header to `$rootdir` using the regular expression.

In the regular expression we extract the actual domain name to the `$domain` variable from the `Host` header by excluding `www.` prefix if it exists. We then use the `$domain` variable to build the `$rootdir` variable.

However, this method might not work with SSL due to reasons mentioned in the comment. In this case you need to implement a configuration management system which generates configuration files for domains from templates.

Comment: I'm not sure about SSL though, AFAIK NGINX loads all certificates at boot time and drops privileges afterwards so this most likely won't work on SSL with multiple certificates.

Comment: Good point, with SSL there might be no way to implement this except a configuration management system. I updated the answer, thanks.